# Vertical centering of multirow cell when using equations inside table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, equations, multirow, vertical

I'm trying to center vertically the first column of this table. As I'm using multirow, the text from the first column should get between matrix "A" and "B".

If I substitute the equations from the second column for any random text, the vertical centering of the first one works. So I guess it's something related to the presence of the equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow} 

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Models}
    \begin{tabular}{C{1.5cm}C{6cm}}
        \toprule

        Model & Matrix \\ 
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Model 1}    & ${\vbox{   \begin{equation}
                A=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation}} }$\\
        & ${\vbox{      \begin{equation}
                B=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation} } }$\\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Model 2}    & ${\vbox{       \begin{equation}
                A=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation} } }$\\
        & ${\vbox{      \begin{equation}
                B=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation} } }$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with paragraphs, rules, or anything not a standard array strut in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most general solution is to overlay the text midway between two `\tikzmark`s.  If you actually want all that space between equations, simply replace `\mathbox` with `\vbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\mathbox}[1]{\bgroup
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \mbox{\vbox{#1}}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Models}
    \begin{tabular}{C{1.5cm}C{6cm}}
        \toprule
        Model & Matrix \\ 
        \midrule
        \tikzmark{row1} &\mathbox{\begin{equation}
                A=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation}}\\
        \tikzmark{row2} &\mathbox{\begin{equation}
                B=\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \end{equation}}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\path (pic cs:row1)--(pic cs:row2)
        node[midway, text width=1.5cm, anchor=base]{Model 1};}%

    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]